# SUM all prices from table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have following SQL query which is summing tourist tax from selected period.

```
SELECT
     BTR_DESCRIPTION AS TOURIST_TAX_NAME,
     ISNULL(BREAG_TOURIST_TAX_PRICE,0) AS PRICE,
     SUM(DATEDIFF(d, BRE_DATEFROM, BRE_DATETO)) AS QUANTITY,
     ISNULL(BREAG_TOURIST_TAX_PRICE,0) * SUM(DATEDIFF(d, BRE_DATEFROM, BRE_DATETO)) AS FINAL_PRICE
FROM BOS_RESERVATION
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BOS_RESADDGUEST ON BREAG_BRE_ID = BRE_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BOS_TAX_REASONS ON BTR_ID = BREAG_BTR_ID
WHERE BREAG_DATEFROM >= '2018-02-28' AND BREAG_DATETO <= '2018-03-31'
GROUP BY BTR_DESCRIPTION, BREAG_TOURIST_TAX_PRICE
```

Query result:

[image]

Now i want to sum all values from FINAL_PRICE row. So the result must be: 5,652
But i dont know how to do this. I tried with following SQL:

```
SUM(ISNULL(BREAG_TOURIST_TAX_PRICE,0) * SUM(DATEDIFF(d, BRE_DATEFROM, BRE_DATETO))) AS FINAL_PRICE_SUM
```

But this gives me error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Can you please help me how to sum all values from FINAL_PRICE row?

Thanks!

Comment: `FINAL_PRICE` is not a "row", it is a "column".  So you question is unclear.

Comment: Try by adding `WITH ROLLUP` to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Remove the group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
WITH AggregatedTable as (SELECT
     BTR_DESCRIPTION AS TOURIST_TAX_NAME,
     ISNULL(BREAG_TOURIST_TAX_PRICE,0) AS PRICE,
     SUM(DATEDIFF(d, BRE_DATEFROM, BRE_DATETO)) AS QUANTITY,
     ISNULL(BREAG_TOURIST_TAX_PRICE,0) * SUM(DATEDIFF(d, BRE_DATEFROM, BRE_DATETO)) AS FINAL_PRICE
FROM BOS_RESERVATION
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BOS_RESADDGUEST ON BREAG_BRE_ID = BRE_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BOS_TAX_REASONS ON BTR_ID = BREAG_BTR_ID
WHERE BREAG_DATEFROM >= '2018-02-28' AND BREAG_DATETO <= '2018-03-31'
GROUP BY BTR_DESCRIPTION, BREAG_TOURIST_TAX_PRICE)

Select at.*, 
    (SELECT SUM(FINAL_PRICE) from AggregatedTable)) as Total_FP 
from AggregatedTable AS at
```

Comment: Thanks you helped me alot!

Comment: @makaroN No probs mate!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total final price, use a CTE or subquery:

```
WITH r as (
      SELECT BTR_DESCRIPTION AS TOURIST_TAX_NAME,
             COALESCE(BREAG_TOURIST_TAX_PRICE, 0) AS PRICE,
             SUM(DATEDIFF(day, BRE_DATEFROM, BRE_DATETO)) AS QUANTITY,
             COALESCE(BREAG_TOURIST_TAX_PRICE, 0) * SUM(DATEDIFF(day, BRE_DATEFROM, BRE_DATETO)) AS FINAL_PRICE
      FROM BOS_RESERVATION LEFT OUTER JOIN
           BOS_RESADDGUEST
           ON BREAG_BRE_ID = BRE_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
           BOS_TAX_REASONS
           ON BTR_ID = BREAG_BTR_ID
      WHERE BREAG_DATEFROM >= '2018-02-28' AND BREAG_DATETO <= '2018-03-31'
      GROUP BY BTR_DESCRIPTION, BREAG_TOURIST_TAX_PRICE
     )
SELECT SUM(FINAL_PRICE)
FROM r;
```

Comment: Thanks you helped me alot!